# Set custom attribute on textfield Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am implementing Stripe in my Sencha Touch 2 application, and they require that I have set a custom data- HTML5 attribute on the respective input fields ala this:

```
<input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
<input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
<input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
<input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
```

I have defined my input fields in the view like this:

```
{
    xtype:'textfield',
    name:'expirationYear',
    'data-stripe':'exp-year',
    label:'Expiration',
    placeHolder:'Expiration Year (YYYY)'
}
```

I was experimenting with adding:

```
'data-stripe':'exp-year',
```

But that naturally didnt work since its not a valid Sencha attribute. How can I set custom attributes on the Sencha textfields to make sure the rendered input fields will be like in the HTML above?

Comment: You need to override the component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sencha Touch 2 does not provide this behaviour out of the box. You will need to extend the `Ext.field.Input` component (which is the internal component for the actual fields in `Ext.field.Text`) and add the functionality to set that `data-stripe` attribute. Here is an untested example of that component:

```
/**
 * @class Ext.ux.field.Stripe
 *
 * An input component to allow setting of `data-stripe` attribute.
 */
Ext.define('Ext.ux.field.Stripe', {
    extend: 'Ext.field.Input',

    config: {
        /**
         * @cfg {String} The value to set for the `data-stripe` attribute on the field
         * @accessor
         */
        data: null
    },

    /**
     * Updates the `data-stripe` attribute with the {@link #stripe} configuration.
     * @private
     */
    updateData: function(newData) {
        this.updateFieldAttribute('data-stripe', newData);
    }
});
```

You can add this to your application by adding it to the 'requires' property of your view:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyView', {
    requires: ['Ext.ux.field.Stripe']
});
```

And you will need to add the following code to the top of your `app.js` file, so the framework knows where to find the custom component:

```
Ext.Loader.setPath({
    'Ext.ux': 'path/to/ux/folder'
});
```

Once you have added that component to your application and required it, you will be able to use it like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'field',
    component: {
        xclass: 'Ext.ux.field.Stripe',
        data: 'exp-month'
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like charm! Thanks!

Comment: But small correction: xtype: 'Ext.ux.field.Stripe', cant be the class name, must be a xtype. I sat a xtype on the Stripe input component and used that instead. Just in case someone comes by this post.

Comment: Sorry, should of been `xclass`. Will fix.

Answer (score 1):

More as an aside, you don't need the custom 'data-' attributes.  Based on the [Stripe.js documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#collecting-card-details), you can call Stripe.card.createToken from your controller with the values from the form directly.