# Setting panel attributes dynamically in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

In Sencha touch 2, how can I set the value of a attribute ( like the html one) using a function?

Example:

```
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        html: function () {
            if (conditionA) return 2
            return 4
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/16998494/2596334

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a self-executing anonymous function:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    html: (function () {
        if (0) {
            return 'lol';
        }
        return 'rofl';
    })()
}
```